# Chances of TELEPHONY_SERVICE return null

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Is there any chances of getting TELEPHONY_SERVICE as null ?

```
     TelephonyManager teleman = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

I mean is there any chances of getting teleman as null in the above line ?

Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: Also don't forget to insert the proper permissions in AndroidManifest when using the TelephonyManager object. Different methods may require different permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can. As [getSystemService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29)'s manual says:

> **Returns**
>
> The service or null if the name does not exist.

For some basic services it is quite unlikely, however telephony is not one of those. Do not expect it on i.e. GoogleTV or some sort of tablets. You can check if certain feature is avaiable by using [hasSystemFeature()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: But I've seen Samsung cellular (CDMA/LTE, in this case) devices where the result of hasSystemFeature changes depending on SIM state.  So, you can have a device with telephony and want to access TelephonyManager, e.g. to find out what the sim state is, but have hasSystemFeature mislead you.  So, better to just try to get the TM and see what it returns.

Comment: I've seen this happen on a Pixel as well @Tom , so I suspect this isn't limited to Samsung.

Comment: "Do not expect it on i.e. GoogleTV or some sort of tablets" - have you verified/seen this behavior before @Marcin? I've never seen a tablet return `null` for `TelephonyManager`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can check with this:

```
 getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)
```